# Disable NHibernate logging

Tags: nhibernate, logging, log4net

I have an **empty** app.config file, but I still get NHibernate debug logs

```
NHibernate: SELECT this_.LogID as LogID71_0_, this_.Level as Level71_0_, this_.Message as Message71_0_, this_.EventTime as EventTime71_0_, this_.Component as ...
```

I tried adding a log4net configuration with an ERROR log level, but no use. How can I stop these log messages?

The thing I'm puzzled about is why do these appear in the first place if I have an empty app.config to being with. It doesn't make sense to me that I have to configure it not to print these messaages - the default should be off. Could it be my code is setting them on programatically somehow? What should I look for?

Comment: As we can see, real asnwer is configuration of log4net

Comment: actually, it's the showsql in nHibernate....

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[Configure Log4Net for use with NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate) may be helpful.

You need to have both these loggers:

```
 <logger name="NHibernate">
   <level value="ERROR" />
 </logger>

 <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
   <level value="ERROR" />
 </logger>
```

Comment: Not working, see updated question (I added the appropriate log4net config section, no effect).

Comment: log4net actually matches logger names starting with the specified name, so putting "NHibernate" will filter out every NHibernate message.

Comment: I think @Ripper's comment is incorrect, this works for me and also with ActiveRecord

Comment: @ChrisS - my comment is not incorrect. This answer works for 99% of the people, but in my case it didn't help. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1488105/11236

Comment: In some cases you may have to set `additivity` property to false to get what you expect, like:

`<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
   <level value="ERROR" />
 </logger>`

Answer (score 14):

```
return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(
                c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyDB")).ShowSql())
```

Removing the `.ShowSql()` worked for me

Comment: But what if I want to see sql, but not in console?

Answer (score 6):

The problem was somewhere in "my code". We build the NHibernate configuration manually (setting the show_sql flag to true).

Answer (score 4):

The NHibernate logs don't help me much... I like these settings better:

```
    <logger name="NHibernate">
      <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
      <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to disable the logging at the NHibernate level or the Log4Net level?

I'm doing the former by setting "show_sql" variable to false. I'm doing this programmatically in C# right now, but I assume this would be easy to put in an XML configuration file as well.

Comment: Not working (http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/nhibernate-log4net.aspx). Why would the default be to show the SQL?

Could it be my code somehow turns this on pragmatically?

Comment: Just went and checked my code. I turned it off by commenting out show_sql = true. Never mind. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the NUnit problem. The extra logging was happening when running the tests in TeamCity which must have been using a different version of nunit

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NUnit 2.4.6? I read [this](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/06/avoid-using-nhibernate-with-nunit-2-4-6/) blog post yesterday which says that this version of NUnit sets log4net to use DEBUG level logging, effecting NHibernate as well.

if it's not NUnit and it's not you, I would check if it's some other 3rd party library that you're using.

**EDIT**

On second thought, I don't think that the output has something to do with log4net. the format looks more like the "show_sql" controlled output. I would check two things:
1. If the correct (the one with the show_sql=false) hibernate.config is copied to your execution directory.
2. If the show_sql configuration property is not overridden manually in your code.